# core data relationship retrieve using key

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following data model relationship (attributes in parenthesis)

Day (date) ----------->> Event (date, name)

There is a one to many relationship from **Day** to **Event**. There is no inverse relationship (i.e the **Event** entity doesn't have a reference to **Day**)

The Events are created first and saved. The Day gets created later.

Is there a way when retrieving the **Day** entity to have core data also go and retrieve every **Event** that has the same date as the date of that Day? I have searched some other questions, but all of them include manually setting the **Events** when the **Day** is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query into `CoreData` with `NSFetchRequest`, which can only query one specific entity type (hence the `initWithEntityName(_:)` initializer).  If you do not have a relationship set between the two entities, you cannot retrieve both of them with a single `NSFetchRequest` instance (you may be able to use the same `NSPredicate`, given that you have a `date` attribute on both).

Having said that, as the answers to the other questions probably indicate, if you have a relationship set you can set the property `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` on the `NSFetchRequest` entity to whatever your relationship key is to fetch the entities for a relationship when you fetch the initial entities.  Assuming your goal is to avoid multiple trips to the database, you may also want to consider setting `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to `false` (only do this if you have a relatively small number of objects).

Comment: From the documentation, that will retrieve Events that are already associated with a Day entity. My question is how to retrieve them without manually associating them

Comment: @robola As I said in my answer "If you do not have a relationship set between the two entities, you cannot retrieve both of them with a single `NSFetchRequest`."

Comment: I do have a relationship. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean, I have a one to many relationship between the Day entity and the Event entity

Comment: @robola I'm not referring to the relationship in your data model, I'm referring to a particular Day instance and one or many Event instances being assigned to one another (via the relationship in your data model).  If you haven't set that, then there is no way to do what you ask with one fetch request.

Comment: Ah. I understand now. Thanks. Marking as answer

Answer (score 0):

As Charles said, just make two fetch requests. The first request to retrieve the **Day**, then a second request to retrieve the **Events** for the same date.

What I would do, though, is to set up the inverse relationship and change the timing of object creation. When creating an **Event**, if there is no **Day** object to link it to, then create a new **Day** object at the same time. If you did it this way, you could then just fetch a **Day** by itself, and its **Events** would be automatically available via the relationship.

Comment: I marked Charles' as the answer since he answered first, but two fetch requests is what I ended up doing. I was trying to see if core data could do it. There are two reasons I can't do the inverse suggestion, the first is that there is not guaranteed to be a Day object for every date, and even if there was, at the time the Event is created, I don't have enough information to create it. This way I can avoid having to check if the Day object is valid when I retrieve it.